# Order a list of files by size via python

Tags: python, arrays, hash, dictionary

Example dump from the list of a directory:

```
hello:3.1 GB
world:1.2 MB
foo:956.2 KB
```

The above list is in the format of FILE:VALUE UNIT. How would one go about ordering each line above according to file size?

I thought perhaps to parse each line for the unit via the pattern ":VALUE UNIT" (or somehow use the delimiter) then run it through the [ConvertAll engine](http://pastie.org/736888), receive the size off each value in bytes, hash it with the rest of the line (filenames), then order the resulting dictionary pairs via size.

Trouble is, I have no idea about pattern matching. But I see that you can sort a [dictionary](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52306/)

If there is a better direction in which to solve this problem, please let me know.

---

**EDIT:**

The list that I had was actually in a file. Taking inspiration from answer of the (awesome) [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli), I've written up the following code that extracts from one file, orders it and writes to another.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

sourceFile = open("SOURCE_FILE_HERE", "r")
allLines = sourceFile.readlines()
sourceFile.close()

print "Reading the entire file into a list."

cleanLines = []

for line in allLines:
    cleanLines.append(line.rstrip())

mult = dict(KB=2**10, MB=2**20, GB=2**30)

def getsize(aline):
  fn, size = aline.split(':', 1)
  value, unit = size.split(' ')
  multiplier = mult[unit]
  return float(value) * multiplier

print "Writing sorted list to file."

cleanLines.sort(key=getsize)

writeLines = open("WRITE_OUT_FILE_HERE",'a')

for line in cleanLines:
    writeLines.write(line+"\n")

writeLines.close()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
thelines = ['hello:3.1 GB', 'world:1.2 MB', 'foo:956.2 KB']

mult = dict(KB=2**10, MB=2**20, GB=2**30)

def getsize(aline):
  fn, size = aline.split(':', 1)
  value, unit = size.split(' ')
  multiplier = mult[unit]
  return float(value) * multiplier

thelines.sort(key=getsize)
print thelines
```

emits `['foo:956.2 KB', 'world:1.2 MB', 'hello:3.1 GB']`, as desired.  You may have to add some entries to `mult` if KB, MB and GB don't exhaust your set of units of interest of course.

Comment: Still extremely helpful 7 years later. Thank you